# Exercise of motonone sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

If $ a_n $ is increasing and $ a_n <0 $ for all $ n $, does $ a_n $ converge?

I think so, since $ a_n $ is increasing and bounded by $ 0 $, that is, it is a monotone sequence. And by theorem, all these sequences converge. True?

Comment: Did you mean *monotonic*?

Comment: Yes, sir. I meant that.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE ^_^

Yes. You are correct that all bounded monotone sequences converge. In particular, your monotone sequence is bounded (it is entirely inside $[a_0, 0]$) so it converges.

We can say slightly more, actually. The limit $\lim a_n$ of a monotone sequence is its supremum $\sup a_n$ (Do you see why?). After you've thought about it, you can see this proven at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lemma_1)
for monotone convergence.

---

I hope this helps ^_^